# How to find the source of inline css

Tags: theming, 8

I'm kind of new to Drupal and I have to work on an already existing site using Drupal 8. In the main menu, when the links are hovered, they take the color of the background which is caused by some inline css tagged `!important` and I don't know how to find the file containing that line. Any idea on where to start?

Answer (score 1):

- [Enable twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392) to pin down the used template file(s) (if the output was added inside of a template). Search the templates before the !important output for that markup.
- If you can't find it look at the preprocess functions used for those templates.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS will be set in whatever theme is active at the time.  To find out, in Drupal 8:

1. Log in
2. Click on "Manage"
3. Click on "Appearance"
4. Look at the list of "Installed Themes"

Once you know which theme you're using, you can search in that for your CSS.

Note that it's best practice to put your theme in /docroot/themes/ (if you're using a built-in theme, copy it to this location and edit that)

Comment: Modules and libraries can add CSS, too.  As well as JS.